Split headerless html table rows 50% left and 50% right
I have 20 rows like this in a standard html table (table>tbody>tr>td) without a header.
current situation
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

I would like to render this like:
desired result
When i use flexbox it will sort 1,2 next line 3,4 etc.
I found loads of results on how to do other things, but not this. I remember it could be done without javascript and without modifying the html - and it was a pure css-thing couple lines long, but can't find that doc anymore. Also searched on stackoverflow, nowhere to be found. If anyone can put me into the correct direction - thanks!

It's hard to say without more context, but this doesn't seem like tabular information. A table might not be the correct way to mark up this content.

I think i can agree with that, modern ways are using divs/sections/etc, also to make it responsive. But i have this table, so have to deal with it. + add some breakpoints and mobiles get a long list and bigger screens get the 50/50. The posts i'm reading do not seem to agree on whats best for SEO, etc. https://html.com/tables/  VS https://www.htmltables.io/blog/beginners-guide-to-html-tables etc. But for some applications it's an easy choice. I also do not agree with code maintenance issue from that one page, maybe for huge/complex tables, but i'm just rendering some basic data in this table.

Tables should only really be used when the content is semantically tabular—e.g., when it has row or column headers and makes the most sense (from an information standpoint) as a grid. Otherwise, other elements should be used—even if it's still presented in a grid-like fashion with CSS.

Here is something that comes close, using CSS columns and display parameters different from the original (table) ones:


table {
  display: block;
}
tbody {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}
tr {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td {
  display: inline;
}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




Thank you, this was what i was looking for. You can also create a wrapper div and set column-count: 2; on that, or on the tbody (i just found out while testing this). Got any documentation where i can find this? Then i'll mark this one as the answer.

documentation on what do you mean? Basically, using these display settings, I am simply deactivating the autmatic table display of all these elements, and using column-count to have it in two columns. Documentation about css columns can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns (also note the links to other column parameters on the left side of that page)

Documentation link, so people after me can click to the source. I believe answers that include links to doc pages (+ explanation) are more valuable, especially for the search engines - comments don't make it that far from what i've seen. I actually visited that page! But could not get it to work. Thanks again for the example. Do have to admit i lean more to the grid option provided by @TemaniAfif, but it looks like your answer is the best for a really simple table like this, that's why i selected this one. No additionals, just change the display and set column-count: done.

CSS grid can also do the job


table,
tbody {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  justify-content: start;
}
table tr {
  grid-column: 1;
}
table tr:nth-child(n + 11) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

/* styling */
tr {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background:  #f2f2f2;
  border:1px solid;
}
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




OP wanted the first 10 in the left column. n + 20 doesn't seem to achieve that, but it's hard to work out how to tweak it to get the result.

@ralph.m uodated

This is also a very interesting option, might even be the better one, cause you do not have to alter the table specs (set block/inline-block on table/tbody/tr/td). I'll test this tomorrow/day after and check up on some docs, see whats best, also for browser support/future-proof-inesh. TBC

@TemaniAfif — Ah, beautiful. I tried that without success, but had forgotten about dense.

The trick is to make sure the width is 50% and you need to gravitate to the left, like
    tr {
       float: left;
       width: 50%;
    }



    tr {
       float: left;
       width: 50%;
    }
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




I was hoping to do it without floating, from what i remember it was not required. But i'll test it for sure. Thanks!
